# Report issue in odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have developed a new report for account.invoice in odoo 12 but when i suppose to print this, it gives me a warning like this in 12.0 branch :

The report's template 'Template name' is wrong, please contact your administrator.

Can not separate file to save as attachment because the report's template does not contains the attributes 'data-oe-model' and 'data-oe-id' on the div with 'article' classname.

In master branch it says data-model instead of data-oe-model, data-id instead of data-oe-id and 'page' classname instead of 'article' classname

If anyone has faced the same issue and find a solution then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the exact same error. I have a report module, which is running from v9 to v11 (adopted along the way with new versions). But in Odoo v12 when I try to print invoice it gives this error 

"The report's template 'Invoices' is wrong, please contact your administrator.

Can not separate file to save as attachment because the report's template does not contains the attributes 'data-oe-model' and 'data-oe-id' on the div with 'article' classname. " Screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/PLBwVVJ

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with a help from a friend:

In your external_layout you have to define 't-att-data-oe-model' and 't-att-data-oe-id' . Add this:

```
<div class="article o_report_layout_standard" t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id">
    <t t-call="web.address_layout"/>
    <t t-raw="0"/>
</div>
```

Previously this piece of code (v11) was like this:

```
<div class="article o_report_layout_standard">
    <t t-raw="0" />
</div>
```

Hope it solves your problem. This change is because the report is now editable in v12 with the studio app.

Comment: Where is one supposed to find this "external_layout"? thanks!

Comment: <t t-call="web.external_layout"></t> by this you can call external_layout

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to modify the external_layout, In my case it was custom layout and i solved it using below XML

```
<template id="custom_layout">
    <!-- Multicompany -->
        <div class="article o_report_layout_standard" t-att-data-oe-model="doc and doc._name" t-att-data-oe-id="doc and doc.id">
            <t t-if ="doc and 'company_id' in doc" >
                <t t-set="company" t-value="doc.company_id"/>
                <t t-set="customer" t-value="doc.partner_id"/>
            </t>
            <t t-call="custom_sale_report_v12.custom_layout_header"/>
            <t t-raw="0"/>
            <t t-call="ce_sale_report_v12.custom_layout_footer"/>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue.

The reason was there is a `t-if` condition before the `<t t-call="web.external_layout">` . The error is coming when ever its value is False.

Answer (score -1):

This error could happen if there is no report_type="qweb-html" for the report_type="qweb-pdf". 
To solve this issue just had both... something like this :

```
<report
        id="report_invoice_html"
        model="MY_MODEL_NAME"
        string="Invoice HTML"
        name="MODULE.report_invoice_view"
        file="MODULE.report_invoice"
        report_type="qweb-html" />

<report
        id="report_invoice_pdf"
        model="MY_MODEL_NAME"
        string="Invoice PDF"
        name="MODULE.report_invoice_view"
        file="MODULE.report_invoice"
        report_type="qweb-pdf" />
```

If you look at the Odoo code source at ir_actions_report.py, you will see a statement comparing set(res_ids) != set(html_ids), if HTML template doesn't exist it return True, and then raise the Error